# Not being able to place Admob right at the bottom of App

Tags: android, admob, android-relativelayout

I'm having some issues with placing admob right at the bottom of the screen. For some odd reason, the Ad just hovers above the bottom.

I would like Admob to be right at the bottom of the screen, any help would he much appreciated!

[image]

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_high"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HodgeMain"
android:layout_above="@+id/ad" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/BoardList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listcolor" >
</ListView>




    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXX"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want your adview is exactly at the bottom?

Comment: I just tried it and it's fine, can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: @Ahmed Ekri I have updated it with a screen shot link in my answer

Comment: @jack Its just due to paddingBottom of your RelativeLayout. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_high"
tools:context=".HodgeMain">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/BoardList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listcolor" >
</ListView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXX"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just removed unnecessarily things and made it bottom and center.

Answer (score 1):

Your Adview is taking padding from bottom. Because the container of your Adview i.e. RelativeLayout have **android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"**

Answer (score 0):

Just move `android:layout_above="@+id/ad"` from `RelativeLayout` to `ListView`.

Comment: I've already tried that and it still doesn't move right to the bottom.